# Redirect to record page after toast event is fired LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I have this below code where i am updating a record. After updating i am calling closemodal() function, which will close the modal and navigate to the detail page.

The issue which i am facing is after update happens it is redirecting to detail page but i am unable to see the toast message.

How can i redirect to detail page after toast message.

```
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
          updateRecord(recordInput)
                    .then(result => {
                        this.message = result;
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Success',
                                message: 'Request Detail updated',
                                variant: 'success'
                            })
                        );
                        // Display fresh data in the form
                        return refreshApex(this.wiredResults);
                    })
    this.closeModal()
```

close modal

```
closeModal() {
    this.openmodel = false;
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            objectApiName: 'Test__C',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the this.closeModal() inside the updateRecord Promise.
Something like below:

```
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
          updateRecord(recordInput)
                    .then(result => {
                        this.message = result;
                        this.dispatchEvent(
                            new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Success',
                                message: 'Request Detail updated',
                                variant: 'success'
                            })
                        );
                        // Display fresh data in the form
                        return refreshApex(this.wiredResults);
                        this.closeModal()
                    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both navigation event and toast event are firing at same time. You do not have close callback in toast.

WorkAround:

You can show toast message for 3 seconds with url to go to that detail page. So that, user can click on it to go to that page when he wants.

However if user does not click on it, You can use setTimeout to navigate to detail page after 3seconds

toast:

```
    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
    "title": "Success!",
                "message": "{0}! See it {1}!",
                "messageData": [
                    'Request Detail updated',
                    {
                        url, // use [NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl] to get url
                        label: 'here'
                    }
                ]
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Navigation:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            objectApiName: 'Test__C',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
    });
},3000);
```

Note: Generate url and use it in both places

Comment: Thanks @learninhmode. Did this solve the issue?